# Separate Controller library in ASP.NET MVC Core framework Pros and Cons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new in ASP.NET MVC Core and have a small query regarding ASP.NET MVC Core framework.
Is it the best way to use a separate class library for Controllers in ASP.NET MVC Core framework?
Can anyone help me to provide some detailed Pros and Cons for a separate class library for Controllers?

Comment: No it is probably not best for a small project, there is a Controllers folder that is just fine, voting to close this question, as it is primarily opinion based

Answer (score 2):

There no reason to do this because what exactly are you separating? The controllers that you write are going to be specific to ASP.NET MVC so you can't reuse them with another framework. There are no pros, you are just making your project more complicated for no reason.